# How to Link 2 Sheets that have the same fields

Tags: qliksense

I am looking for some help with trying to link 2 sheets that have a number of Filters that I have setup but are both sitting in separate tables. The reason this is because I have a number of aggregated columns that are different for the 2 tables and want to keep this separately as I will be building more sheets as I go along.

The filters that are the same within the 2 sheets are the following:

we_date
product
manager
patch

Through the data manager I managed to create an association between the 2 tables for we_date but from reading on this site and other searches on Google I can't make any associations between these tables and this is where I am stuck.

The 2 sheets will now allow me to filter using the we_date, but if I use the filters for product, manager or patch then nothing happens on my 2nd sheet as they are not linked.

Currently in my data load editor I have 2 sections of select queries like the following:

```
Table1

QUALIFY *;
w:
SELECT
*
FROM
table1
;
UNQUALIFY *;

Table2

QUALIFY *;
w_c:
SELECT
*
FROM
table2
;
UNQUALIFY *;
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could advise a fix on the issue I am having.

Comment: I have tried to associate the fields but you can't have more than 1 in any of the tables and also managed to look at concatenating but need the fields to stay individual rather than being combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qlik, field names of identical values from different tables are **automatically associated**.

When you're calling `Qualify *`, you're actually renaming *all* field names and explicitly saying NOT to associate.

Take a look at the Qlik Sense documentation on `Qualify *`:

> The automatic join between fields with the same name in different
>   tables can be suspended by means of the qualify statement, which
>   qualifies the field name with its table name. If qualified, the field
>   name(s) will be renamed when found in a table. The new name will be in
>   the form of tablename.fieldname. Tablename is equivalent to the label
>   of the current table, or, if no label exists, to the name appearing
>   after from in LOAD and SELECT statements.

---

We can use `as` to manually reassign field names.

```
SELECT customer_id, private_info as "private_info_1", favorite_dog from table1;
SELECT customer_id, private_info as "private_info_2", car from table2;
```

Or, we can correctly use `Qualify`. Example:

table1 and table2 have a customer_id field, and private_info field. We want customer_id field to be the associative value, and private_info to not be. We would use `QUALIFY` on private_info, which Qlik would then rename based on file name.

```
QUALIFY private_info;
SELECT * from table1;
SELECT * from table2;
```

The following field names would then be: customer_id (associated), and table1.private_info, and table2.private_info

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation, didn't realise thats what Qualify did, really appreciated it.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. Good luck on your Qlik journey!